# Best practices in model structure in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Is it ok to have structure like this and duplicating `id` inside of 
the object or it's redundant? It just looks to me that with this structure I could easily query person related stuff and filter persons inside of my Redux store.

```
{
  'persons': {
    'person-1': {
      'id': 'person-1',
      'name': 'John Doe'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on usage.

There is nothing technically wrong with that structure, however, it's often good practice to disassociate your node names from the child data stored within.

Also, it would be redundant in the sense that; if you are looking for person-1's data you could access it directly at

> /root/persons/person-1

instead of dealing with the overhead of an actual query.

Comment: Indeed that's how I'm going to access it. The problem is that if have two persons in my store and I want to compare them the easiest way is to do it by id. That's why I'm puzzled if I should include id inside of an object or not.

Comment: I think the same thing applies: if you have two persons in your store and want to compare them, you will know their user id, so you can read in /root/persons/person-1 and /root/persons/person-2.  If you wanted to craft a query to read in X number of people, you would have to have some kind of commonality between their children to retrieve the ones you are interested in; i.e. all people that are age = 30 or all people that shoeSize = 13.5. Firebase doesn't directly have an AND or OR type query so reading in where person = person_1 or person = person_2 isn't a direct option.